# Tomcat9 slow response with security manager in OpenJdk11

Tags: java, tomcat9, securitymanager, openjdk-11, java-security-manager

We added -Djava.security.manager parameter in java options of tomcat9 to enable security manager . Tomcat is running without any issue but when I try to perform some operation then it takes 9-10 min to process that(login, logout of deployed application or accessing one of the servlet directly) and also no error in log file. If I remove this parameter then there is no delay.

This issue is only visible with java11. Till Java 8 it works fine without any issue.

e.g. Security manager + tomcat9+ java 11= slowness in performing any operation

Security manager + tomcat9+ java 8= Working as expected

Comment: Have you tried taking a thread dump to see where it is stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Adding permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessSystemModules"; in catalina.policy solve the issue as it required defineClassInPackage.java.* permission.
In java 8 it will work without giving accessSystemModule however, that's required in java 11